# unable add maven repository selenium showing error like below

Tags: maven, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver, base-class

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
    - Non-parseable POM C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Website_Project\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'dependency' (position: START_TAG seen ...- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit --
     >\r\n<dependency>... @40:13)
    - Invalid element name: - dependency One of the following is expected: - groupId - artifactId - version - extensions - executions - dependencies - goals - inherited - configuration Error indicated by: {http://
     maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0} with code:
```

Comment: mvnrepository is not a consumable repository.

Comment: Without your POM we cannot really say what your error is.

Comment: this is not a clear question. add the code and efforts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.